# Background issue in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am very new to building websites. I would like to change the background of my pages to a solid colour. Currently the theme I am using is SKT Full Width and the background is opaque. I have a slider in the background and you can see the text that I have added to my page, it does not look good.

I just want my pages to have a solid background colour, but I want to keep the buttons and the text on the slider. If you want to see what my problem is, go to my website and click on any page www.mydeparturez.com.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very vague. How are we supposed to know how proficient you are with web development? None of us have this theme and are willing to download it, pay for it, or test this for you. A better question would be phrased "New to WordPress, I'm using this theme, and the background is opaque. I need it to be a solid color. Do I do this through FTP, do I change it in WordPress?" and then provide examples of what you have, or haven't, tried previously.

Coming in with little to no knowledge of what you're doing, while asking for assistance, is akin to asking someone to personally install a radiator in your car for free. However, I will assist with the problem at hand.

Login to WordPress, and inside of your dashboard hover over the button `Appearance`. Click on `Editor`. You will be placed into the `style.css` of your website.

Scroll to the bottom of this newly opened `style.css` and type in:

```
background: #000 !important;
```

This will make your background black, but not to fear! [Use this tool](http://www.hexcolortool.com/) to find the color you desire, copy the 6 digit hex code `#------` and replace the `#000` with it. Save and update the page. Then test your site.

This is a hacky solution but it will work.

Comment: Sorry, the text still appears in the background of my page because the page is layered on top of the header loading in the background. My main problem is the code that I have added into header.php       <div 

style="text-align:right;position:fixed;

padding:11px;
background:rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.6);
width:610px;
right:40px;
bottom:350px;

font-size: 34px;
margin-top: 9%;

"class="slide-title"> Exotic Luxury Vacations, Browse our Premium Destinations and Check out Vacation Democracy for the hottest destinations being chosen <code><br /></code>
<----------------------------------- </div>

Comment: I just want a solid background. If this cant be done then I will just find a better theme and learn how to code properly. Thanks for you time.

Comment: replace background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) with background: black;

Comment: I've upvoted this for helpfulness, but in my opinion it contained rather too much meta commentary. In general if you can address your answers to a wide audience, and not specifically to the OP, that helps create a mindset for better answers. I've left a bit of the writing advice in my edit, but requests for the tick mark or about downvoting are not of interest to future readers, and they tend to be removed over time.

Comment: @halfer thank you for the notes, I have read them and adjusted accordingly. I appreciate the time for constructive criticism in serving the community!